# How to split this text using JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, subtitle, video-subtitles

I would like to split this text. I am trying to do it with JavaScript regular expression.

*(1) Really not. (2) Uh huh. (3) Behold Prince (4) are key in his natural element, cowering at the mercy of the women in his life. (5) See me perhaps you'd like to spout with my daughters and teach them some combination. (6) No doubt you are the best teacher, your majesty. (7) It is my daughter's that teach me in the languages of the modern world, for instance.*

I would like to parse it to groups of fragments. I am looking for one of these results.

```js
[
  [1, "Really not."],
  [2, "Uh huh."],
  [3, "Behold Prince"],
]


[
  {id: 1, text: "Really not."},
  {id: 2, text: "Uh huh."},
  {id: 3, text: "Behold Prince"},
]
```

I use this pattern.

```js
/\(([0-9])\){1,3}(.+?)\(/g
```

Could you help me, please? What pattern should I use to split the text properly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `array.map`

Comment: Why is the result supposed to contain only the first three of those “elements”, what about the rest of your input string?

Comment: ... just as a side note; all purely *regex* and `matchAll` based approaches which rely on an opening paren for detecting the termination of a text fragment will fail as soon as an opening paren does occur as part of the text content (due to being an allowed character). A more simple `split` / `reduce` based approach is more reliable for covering such an edge case.

Comment: You should select an answer if it solved your problem by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex and string.matchAll function in javascript to do what you want

```js
const str = `(1) Really not. (2) Uh huh. (3) Behold Prince (4) are key in his natural element, cowering at the mercy of the women in his life. (5) See me perhaps you'd like to spout with my daughters and teach them some combination. (6) No doubt you are the best teacher, your majesty. (7) It is my daughter's that teach me in the languages of the modern world, for instance.`;

let array = [...str.matchAll(/\(([0-9]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\()/g)].map(a=>[+a[1],a[2]])

console.log(array)
```

I updated my answer using [The fourth bird's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67805003/13976487) because it is alot cleaner than the regex I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of matching the `(` you can assert it or either the end of the string.

This part `\){1,3}` means repeating the closing parenthesis 1-3 times.

If you want to match 1-3 digits:

```
\(([0-9]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\()
```

- `\(` Match `(`
- `([0-9]+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1** *(Denoted by `m[1]` in the code)*
- `\)` Match `)`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture as least as possible chars in  **group 2** *(Denoted by `m[2]` in the code)*
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chas
- `(?=$|\()` Assert either the end of string or `(` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ngMMlE/1)

```js
const regex = /\(([0-9]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=$|\()/g;
const str = `(1) Really not. (2) Uh huh. (3) Behold Prince (4) are key in his natural element, cowering at the mercy of the women in his life. (5) See me perhaps you'd like to spout with my daughters and teach them some combination. (6) No doubt you are the best teacher, your majesty. (7) It is my daughter's that teach me in the languages of the modern world, for instance.`;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]]));
```

Comment: It was a valuable lesson for me. I am really grateful for your help.

Comment: @TodorIliev You are welcome :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

... an approach based on [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) as well as on [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which uses [*named capture groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) and a [*positive lookahead*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) ... [`/\((?<id>\d+)\)\s*(?<text>.*?)\s*(?=$|\()/g`](https://regex101.com/r/r39BoJ/1/) ...

```js
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/r39BoJ/1]
const regX = (/\((?<id>\d+)\)\s*(?<text>.*?)\s*(?=$|\()/g);

const text = "(1) Really not. (2) Uh huh. (3) Behold Prince (4) are key in his natural element, cowering at the mercy of the women in his life. (5) See me perhaps you'd like to spout with my daughters and teach them some combination. (6) No doubt you are the best teacher, your majesty. (7) It is my daughter's that teach me in the languages of the modern world, for instance."

console.log([
  ...text.matchAll(regX)
  ].map(
    ({groups: { id, text }}) => ({ id: Number(id), text })
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Note***

The above approach does not cover the occurrence (allowed existence) of an opening paren/`(` within a text fragment. Thus, in order to always be on the save side, the OP should consider a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) / [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach ...

```js
const text = "  (1) Really not. (2) Uh (huh). (3) Behold Prince (4) are key in his natural element, cowering at the mercy of the women in his life. (5) See me perhaps you'd like to spout with my daughters and teach them some combination. (6) No doubt you are the best teacher, your majesty. (7) It is my daughter's that teach me in the languages of the modern world, (for instance).  "

console.log(
  text
    .split(/\s*\((\d+)\)\s*/)
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((list, item, idx) => {
      if (idx % 2 === 0) {
        list.push({ id: Number(item) });
      } else {
        // list.at(-1).text = item;
        list[list.length - 1].text = item.trim();
      }
      return list;
    }, [])
);

// test / check ...
console.log(
  'text.split(/\s*\((\d+)\)\s*/) ...',
  text.split(/\s*\((\d+)\)\s*/)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```